# Add text to field loaded from external JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add text to a textarea on a form using jQuery.  The form loads via JS from an external site.

[Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/azzurij/LXWBs/)

The textarea is the 'When would you like a demo?' field.  I believe it is this field.

```
<textarea name="Demo" class="k_textarea k_required" id="Question_1"/>
```

I've tried referencing the field directly by ID (see fiddle) and used a delay in case this was a resource loading order issue.  Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`$(document).ready`](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) event instead of `window.load`.

[<kbd>jsFiddle Demo</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/LXWBs/2/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var input = $( '#Question_1');
    input.val( input.val() + "Contribution to a certain fund");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Fiddle already does a `window.onload` if I recall correctly, that's why your example isn't working.

Change it to a jQuerys dom ready callback.

Btw, since Javascript is synchronous, loading order issue isn't a problem (as long as you don't introduce ajax ofc).